# How to prevent useSWR trigger re-renders when state change in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am facing a problem with re-renders in React, I have a two hooks like code below:

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false); // toggle modal
const { data } = useSWR('my_key_swr', fetcher); 

console.log(data); // 'data' will re-renders everytime 'open' change
```

How I can prevent useSWR re-renders when `open` state change ? Because those re-renders are unnecessary for me.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it inside `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => { console.log(data); }, [data])
```

Comment: the `data` I am use to render to UI, how `useEffect()` in this case work?